# Using Expression Design to produce vector icons for WPF

Tags: wpf, expression-design

I was toying with the idea of switching over to using XAML based icons instead of PNG-based icons, in a Visual Studio-based WPF project.

I can create reasonable and decent icons with Expression Design. but I don't get how the workflow from Expression Design to Visual Studio is supposed to work. I can export to a temporary file in WPF resource dictionary format, and then cut and paste into an actual resource dictionary in my project. I suppose. But that's getting really tedious.

How are you SUPPOSED to do this? (Export from Expression Design into a visual studio project).

fwiw, Expression Blend seems unusable for creating icons. It just doesn't play well with canvases. And Expression Design does have horrifying shortcomings and limitations. But I'd rather use a tool that's built to generate ARTWORK, rather than UI.

Is there a way to do this, and use use PACK URI's, since the project is currently heavily pack-uri based.

I think the piece I'm missing is there doesn't seem to be a standardized XAML format for image files.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using Blend to create icons was always problem. I don't know how to make it simple but i could suggest a third party application for icons.. you can get it free [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio)... It was Syncfusion's Metro studio where you get thousands of icons and you can export as well as png and xaml path... Its it a pre designed icons you can make use of it..